# Problem with consuming an Observable in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, angular6

I have a simple component structure where I have an angular component called `gameplay`, inside which is a child component called `question-box`. The objective is to fetch a simple string via a backend service in gameplay (which works fine), and pass this string to the `question-box` to be displayed (which doesn't work).

Here is my code:

gameplay.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { QuestionsService } from '../services/questions.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-gameplay',
  templateUrl: './gameplay.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gameplay.component.css'],
})
export class GameplayComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private qService: QuestionsService) {

  }

  currentQuestion: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.qService.getQuestions().subscribe({
      next(data) {
        this.currentQuestion = data[0].question;
        console.log(this.currentQuestion); //logs correctly
      },
      complete() { console.log('Done')},
      error() { console.log('Error')},

    })
  }
}
```

gameplay.component.html:

```
<app-question-box [question]="currentQuestion"></app-question-box>
```

question-box.component.ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChange } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-question-box',
  templateUrl: './question-box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./question-box.component.css']
})
export class QuestionBoxComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() question: string;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

question-box.component.html

```
<mat-card md-colors="{background: 'orange'}">
  <mat-card-content>
    <p>{{question}} </p>
  </mat-card-content>

</mat-card>
```

I tried using the async pipe in the template, but it didn't work.
I expect to see the string I got in `next()` in the child's `<p>`; but I don't see anything. The string gets logged correctly on the console, however.

Any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if I left out some information needed to find a solution. Thanks.

Comment: you need to remove the brackets juste after subscribe : `subscribe(fn, fn, fn)`

Comment: Thanks. Gonna try that

Comment: @Cétia: Looks like that's just a syntax difference. https://angular.io/guide/observables.  Anyway, like I said, the next method seems to work because I see the console log correctly.

Comment: do you use Http or HttpClient service?

Comment: I think you should try replacing  `next(data) { ... }` by `(data) => { ... }` not 100% sure, but i think in your solution the `this` inside the callback is the callback-function, not the component itself. And you need to remove the brackets as Cetia said.

Comment: @Marcel: Thanks it worked. If you or Celia post it as an answer I'd be happy to accept. Lesson learned. When in doubt, use arrow functions. No `this` issues.

Comment: @Snowman, add my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my comment:

If you pass the callbacks this way, the `this` inside the callbacks is the function, not the component itself.

Changing to arrow functions will solve the problem:

```
this.qService.getQuestions().subscribe(
      data => this.currentQuestion = data[0].question,
      error => console.log('Error'),
      () => console.log('Done')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add an `ngOnChanges` to the child component to check if the change has been propagated... something like this:

```
ngOnInit(change: any) {
    console.log(change['question']);
}
```

Also, try changing the `ngOnInit` in the parent to be like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.qService.getQuestions().subscribe(
      data => {
         this.currentQuestion = data[0].question;
         console.log(this.currentQuestion); //logs correctly
      },
      error =>  console.log('Error')

    );
}
```